# Reference another Combobox's SelectedItemChange event in a EventTrigger(Storyboard)

Tags: c#, xaml, storyboard

I have the following situation, where I have a Combobox1 and then I have TextBlock (ImportantText) in XAML. What I'm trying to do, is to trigger TextBlock's EventTrigger, and thus the Storyboard when user changes the Combobox's selection. I would like to do this in the xaml-side only.

Any suggestions?

```
    <ComboBox Name="Combobox1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,-5,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}"
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStuff}" ></ComboBox>

                <TextBlock Name="ImportantText" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="This text should appear after user changes the combobox's selection!" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent=" I'm not sure how to reference Combobox1 here! " ></EventTrigger>
                    <BeginStoryboard>

                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ImportantText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" AutoReverse="False" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:5"></DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>

                </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Use the `SourceName` property to refer to the combobox. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.eventtrigger.sourcename?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but how do I refer to the event, when user selects something? All I can find by using the SourceName are properties like IsEnabled etc.

Comment: Hhm, seems difficult to use SourceName and TargetName in a normal style (not template). Maybe you need to do it in code-behind.

Comment: It seems so. It is very easy to do by binding to another boolean value and using that to show/hide the text, but it would have been nice to do it in XAML alone. Thanks for your suggestions!